# fprintf causing commas in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to output table data to a .dat file where I separate the rows by newlines and the column data by commas.  I have this written for the first few rows:

```
fileID = fopen(strcat(filename,'.dat'), 'wt');    
fprintf(fileID, '"","","","","","","",""\n');
fprintf(fileID, '"TIMESTAMP","RECORD","MuxAddress","Averages"\n');
fclose(fileID);
```

This should generate this text in the file:

```
"","","","","","","",""
"TIMESTAMP","RECORD","MuxAddress","Averages"
```

Unfortunately, the code actually generates this text:

```
"","","","","","","","",
"TIMESTAMP","RECORD","MuxAddress","Averages",
```

Which you can see has commas at the end of each line.  This issue breaks a viewer program that I am using, and I can see no way to fix it.  I have not found anyone else saying they have this issue either.

I have done some testing, and if I do a fprintf by itself with a newline, it does not put a comma, but as soon as I put a second fprintf, it creates commas at the end of both lines.

Comment: Then you must be running code that's different than what you've posted here. Change `fileID` to `1` to check and you'll see in your workspace that it doesn't print a trailing comma.

Comment: I am not.  That is what is confusing me.

Comment: Unless you've redefined `fprintf`, then yes you are. Please do the check I proposed above. I'm assuming that you're opening up a different file than the one you're writing to.

Comment: If I change the fileID to 1, the commas are not there, but if I change it back to the fileID, they are still being put in the file..

Comment: Then post the `fopen` and `fclose` commands above so that we can reproduce your issue. Also be sure to delete the file. I think you'll find that with a fresh file the commas are not there.

Comment: I've edited the original post to include the open and close statements

Comment: Yea still can't reproduce it. Did you delete the file and run it again. You won't get commas

Comment: Also put `dbtype(strcat(filename, '.dat'))` at the end and you too will see there are no commas.

Comment: Actually, I did the dbtype, and it does show the commas

Comment: Then you aren't pasting the code exactly as you have it in your own code. Type `which fprintf`

Comment: built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\matlab\iofun\fprintf)

Comment: How have you defined `filename`? That's the only thing I see that remains.

Comment: 'C:\Users\TRANSCEND\Desktop\datfile'

Comment: How are you checking your file? Are you opening it in an external program? Have you tried other programs?

Comment: What OS are you in, because I tested it on a mac and it worked.

Comment: @vtleavs Mac, Linux, Windows and all versions between R2008a and R2016b and no commas.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that it all came down to file permissions.  In the specific case with overwriting the file instead of appending it, the code would add the commas.  I never discovered WHY the commas were being added, but I did find that if I appended the file instead of overwriting they went away.